# 2 collection view cells in one controller

Tags: swift, collections

I want to have 2 collection view cells in one controller, how do I handle the part where the collection view cell is selected in order to perform certain tasks? Here is my code, but is not working, please help.

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if let cell = latestNewsCollectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath){
        print("latest selected")    
    }
    if let cell = promotionCollectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath){   
        print("promotion selected")
    }
```

The output I get is:

```
latest selected

promotion selected
```

In the end all collection view cells are selected, how can I solve this?

Comment: You are taking about 2 `collectionViewCell` and then compare 2 `collectionView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put a check inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.
But declare your Collection Views and connect there IBOutlets.

```
@IBOutlet var collectionView1:UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet var collectionView2:UICollectionView!
```

Then, put check like this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


    if let collectionView == collectionView1 {

        print("latest selected")

    }

    if let collectionView == collectionView2 {

        print("promotion selected")

    }
}
```